# Is there any way to create relationship in mysql workbench by csv-file?

Tags: csv, mysql-workbench

Good day.

I have a CSV-file with 229 headered columns. Is there any way to create a relationship in MySQL workbench 8.0 automatically? I don't want to make all 229 attributes myself. As I understood the 'load' command works only for tables with the given structure.